# Complex Fourier Series of $|x|$

Tags: fourier-series

How would I write the Fourier series for $|x|$ in complex form over the interval $[-2,2]$? I have already tried writing
$$|x|=\sum c_ne^{i\pi nx/2}$$
where
\begin{align*}c_n&=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-2}^{2}|x|e^{-i\pi nx/2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_{-2}^0-xe^{-i\pi nx/2}dx+\int_0^2xe^{-i\pi nx/2}dx\right)
\end{align*}
but that integral seems hopelessly complicated to evaluate. I also have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424961/fourier-series-for-x) previous post involving $|x|$, but it involves a different interval.

Comment: And why would the different interval prevent you from using the same approach, i.e. partial integration?

Comment: I apologize, I think I misread the previous solution. I thought that having a 2 instead of a $\pi$ somehow prevented me from evaluating the exponent in the integral; i.e $e^{i2nx}$ instead of $e^{i\pi nx}$ I will try again with renewed faith.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Integration by parts $$
  \int_a^b \underbrace{x}_{=u}\, \underbrace{e^{\lambda x}}_{=v'} \,dx
  = \bigg(\underbrace{x}_{=u}\,\underbrace{\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda}}_{=v}\bigg)\Bigg|_a^b - \int_a^b \underbrace{1}_{u'}\,\underbrace{\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda}}_{=v} \,dx
$$

Comment: To the intrepid reader: what is called "partial integration" here is more commonly (to my knowledge) referred to "integration by parts".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Uh, sorry, I guess I translated the german word "Partielle Integration" literally. Will fix.

Comment: Not a problem; I only put the comment there because it took *me* an embarrassing amount of time to make the connection